# Unable to get all Google Spreadsheets in V4 API version

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am having trouble with Google Spreadsheets REST API of V4.

I want to fetch all the spreadsheet in my application, but I can't see anywhere to [fetch all spreadsheets in V4](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get), while it's available in [legacy API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/worksheets).

Has Google deprecated that API in V4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting in touch with Google Doc, I got my answer.

I gone through with V3 & V4 version for `List of Spreadsheet` but as they mentioned that they have replicated that API with `Google Drive` rest API with `mimeType`  `application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet`,

the working URL is: `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'`